# dual color for product title -elementor-wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want the "product title" of my products have two different colors.
for example the product name is:
200w solar panel
I want the "solar panel" becomes yellow and "200w" becomes black.
what css code should I use in elemontor?
I want to use this code on single product template and the product title comes for
wooCommerce.

I can only write css code